# Creating an empty directory to docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How do I create an empty folder inside a docker container using a Dockerfile?

I guess I could just copy an empty folder from source as an empty "backup" directory to the container like:

```
COPY empty_dir backup
```

... but what I would like to do, is just to create the folder without referring to anything existing.
A script running in the container would need to access this folder later on to copy some backup-files into it.
Is there a command like *MKDIR* to be used in the Dockerfile?

Simple question, but couldn't find answer to it (easily at least).

Comment: depends on whether you are building a linux based (most likely) or windows based (rather unlikely) image. just use `RUN mkdir -p /path/to/directory` or `RUN mkdir c:\path\to\directory`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create it with :

```
RUN mkdir -p /path/to/my/myemptydir
```

`-p` allows to make intermediate directories.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

```
RUN mkdir -p /xxx/yyy
```